# What happened to all the Barrys in the scene where his mom died?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

Throughout *The Flash* we have seen that during the moment Barry's mother dies there is one Barry that is fighting with Thawne (Barry 1) and saves the kid Barry (Barry Prime). Then in one of the seasons Barry travels back in time and hides in a closet to save his mum (Barry 2) but Barry 1 tells him not to do it. Then at the end of season 2 another Barry goes back in time and saves his mother (Barry 3) and then another Barry goes back in time with the help of Thawne to stop the other Barry from saving his mum. So in total we have four Barry Allens in the same room. How come none of them collided or saw each other (except Barry 1 and 2 as I explained)?

Comment: The speed force.

Comment: Could the downvoter care to explain why he downvoted

Comment: Related? - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61569/what-happened-to-the-child-barry-allen-in-the-flash-s3-premiere

Comment: Season 1 Flash is behind the door (flash 1). Future flash (flash 2) took Barry (child) to a safe location so is out of the picture. Then there is season 2 flash (creator of flashpoint - flash 3) and finally season 3 flash (flash 4). Flash 1 is overwritten by flash 4 which means flash 3 never happened. Flash 2 was busy hiding child Barry. At least thats how I understood it.

Comment: Seems plausible

Answer (score 1):

When Barry went back to save his mom, there were 3 Barrys in the room. Since Barry stopped his mother from getting killed, an alternate timeline was created in which Barrys mom was not killed. Now when Barry 4 took reverse flash back to kill his mother, another Timeline is created. Now Barry's mom exists on 3 different timeline and Barry only exists in one

Comment: I haven't seen this episode, but definately sounds like fun way to look at "variable exhanges" :D