# How did Nora do this in The Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

Okay, so I'm a little confused about the event that occurred at the end of Season 4.

As you may know, Barry's daughter revealed herself after saving his life. How could she have saved his life in the past? If he was going to die she wouldn't even exist to come save his life. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Ohhh...time / multiverse paradox....never get enough of those.

Comment: Semi-related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61569/what-happened-to-the-child-barry-allen-in-the-flash-s3-premiere

Comment: The question you found was for s3 :). It doesn't talk about his daughter (which is who I'm asking about).

Comment: That's why its **related**...not an answer. The assumption is that Nora has created her own Flashpoint...just like Barry did.

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm still new to using stackoverflow.

Comment: Since this is purely speculative and may be explained in the future, I'm not going to post it as an answer, but perhaps Nora had travelled back in time (to visit her parents' wedding for example), and realised that the crashing satellite might wipe her from existence if it killed her father, and helped out.  The appearance afterward at the West home may be because she tried to return home to the future and discovered that it was totally different than she remembered, hence returning to ask for help...

Comment: A theory is that Iris is already pregnant at the end of Season 4.